# Objective-C created a PDF, can I add background colour?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a PDF with the code below:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = @"test.pdf";
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:documentsDirectory, filename, nil]];

CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, NULL, NULL);
CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);

CGRect bounds = CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(pdfContext);
CGContextScaleCTM(pdfContext, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0.0, -bounds.size.height);

UIFont *headerFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:8];

NSDictionary *headerAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: headerFont};

[@"Task" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10) withAttributes:headerAttributes];

UIGraphicsPopContext();
CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);
```

My question is, can I add a background colour as an attribute? for this

```
[@"Task" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10) withAttributes:headerAttributes];
```

I will be adding multiple items and they will all have different background colours, I am just asking if this is possible?

Comment: See NSAttributedString.h.  There are many attributes you can use when rendering text, including `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` and `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName`.

Comment: Perfect. that worked, put in an answer and ill approve

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this by using `NSAttributedString` and the relative properties, but for sanity I would recommend [this library](https://github.com/brentnycum/BNHtmlPdfKit). I've found `NSAttributedString` to be insanely verbose and (personally) have enjoyed having my styling happen in a leaner language. *Note that I have nothing to do with this library but it really helped*